# How to fetch the Value of Teamcity Configuration in java?

Tags: teamcity

I have a piece of java code where I have to display the Teamcity build configuration name. This piece of code will be executed in one of the steps configured for the configuration.

can we read value of the env variable %env.TEAMCITY_BUILDCONF_NAME% set in Teamcity configuration settings and use  or is there anyother way of o fetching the Value of Teamcity Configuration Name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, you just need to read the environment variable value in the code.

This should get what you need:

```
final String buildConfigName = System.getenv("TEAMCITY_BUILDCONF_NAME");
```

Comment: TeamCity does provide Configuration parameters (like teamcity.build.id) and System property (like system.teamcity.auth.userId) but I don't know how to access these using Java.