# TeamCity :: How can I access teamcity build ID in Java

Tags: java, selenium, continuous-integration, teamcity, bamboo

Teamcity Build ID (which is different from BUILD_NUMBER) is used in various URLs. I want to send an email having path of a build's artifacts/ overview etc.

In Java, we can get currently running teamcity build number as follows:

```
String tc_BuildNumber = System.getenv("BUILD_NUMBER");
```

This is because TC provides an environment variable namely BUILD_NUMBER.
But unfortunately, there is no environment variable corresponding to BUILD_ID.

TeamCity does provide Configuration parameters (like teamcity.build.id) and System property (like system.teamcity.auth.userId) but I don't know how to access these using Java. I want to read the value of teamCity.build.id jusy like we can read environment variables names mentioned in [How to fetch the Value of Teamcity Configuration in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30751034/how-to-fetch-the-value-of-teamcity-configuration-in-java)

Comment: Are you executing your code from inside of TeamCity plugin?

Comment: Above code in Java class file. If the java project is ran through one of TC build steps, above line gets executed and gives current build number.

Comment: The build id is not exposed as environment variable.  Did you check any other way of including URL is good enough -- https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Patterns+For+Accessing+Build+Artifacts

Comment: Hay @Jayan.The link shared by you worked for me. I would be glad to share the bounty to you. Could you please put your comment as answer. I will accept that..

Answer (score 7):

Are you executing the java code using a build runner?

If so, then you should be able to pass %system.teamcity.build.id% to the runner, and make it available to your code.

i.e. If you're using the command line runner

```
java -Dbuild_id=%system.teamcity.build.id%
```

which you can then access as system arguments

Or if you're using gradle, you can do something like

```
if (project.hasProperty("teamcity")) {
    version = project.teamcity["teamcity.build.id"]
}
```

and pass 'version' to the java command line.

In maven, you can just access it using:

```
${teamcity.build.id}
```

in your pom.xml

(I could do with a little more info about how you're running java to answer this specifically)

Comment: Hi. I don't want to set the variable beforehand instead I want to read its value during execution

Comment: Yes, but during execution of what? The build, or when you're running the jar which is built from that build?

Comment: here I am referring to the execution of build. Thanks.

Comment: Then i have answered your question, it is available in your build runner using the code I've shown

Comment: From maven I don't want to pass system.teamcity.build.id as param. Instead system.teamcity.build.id is a system parameter present in TeamCity. I want to read this value as it is needed in URL of a artifact and this value changes with every build. I am really appreciating your help and would be very happy to give bounty points if I get the answer I need.

Comment: This is the first time you mentioned maven! You can just access the variable directly in maven using ${teamcity.build.id} - I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed that lots of people want to know the answer to this question.
Fortunately with the help of comment from @Jayan I was able to do solve my exact problem which was how to get URL for build artifacts.

As mentioned in link https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Patterns+For+Accessing+Build+Artifacts, by default, TeamCity uses Internal Build ID for the path that can be used to access build artifacts:

```
/repository/download/BUILD_TYPE_EXT_ID/BUILD_ID:id/ARTIFACT_PATH
```

Accessing build Id could be difficult in the runtime(That is the reason of this question), but we can also use Build Number to access artifacts

```
/repository/download/BUILD_TYPE_EXT_ID/BUILD_NUMBER/ARTIFACT_PATH
```

And as shown in my question build number can be accessed as

```
String BUILD_NUMBER= System.getenv("BUILD_NUMBER");
```

and

```
String BUILD_TYPE_EXT_ID = System.getenv("TEAMCITY_BUILDCONF_NAME");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you can create env var with value "%system.teamcity.buildType.id%" and read it in build. After that you can do an api request like:

```
$APIURL = "${API_BaseUrl}/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/?locator=buildType:${API_BuildType},state:running,count:1"

$APIXML = (Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $API_CredentialsHeader -Credential $API_Credentials -Uri $APIURL -Method GET -ContentType "application/xml" -TimeoutSec 20)
# Here you build id.
$APIXML.builds.build.id
```

This is PS example. But idea the same. In Java that might be more easy.

Comment: Hi. I don't want to set the variable beforehand instead I want to read its value during execution

Answer (score 0):

A link to a TeamCity build can use build number instead of buildID. But, it requires buildTypeId as well (can be seen in build configuration page URL).

A sample of such link is:

`https://buildserver/viewLog.html?buildTypeId=Project_Trunk&buildNumber=46523`

Hope this helps someone.